# Trouble with node bcrypt installation

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, bcrypt

I am learning [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org). So I just want to encrypt password using node module bcrypt.

`npm install bcrypt` is the command what I use to install bcrypt modules, I came to know that it has many dependencies, I intalled node-gyp as well `npm install -g node-gyp`

Can anyone suggest how can I get it resolved?

Error :

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  blowfish.cc
  bcrypt.cc
  bcrypt_node.cc

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): warning
C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specif
y /EHsc [c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\backup\My-Twitter\node_modules\bcrypt\
build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(38): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openss
l/rand.h': No such file or directory [c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\backup\My
-Twitter\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\backup\My-Twitter\node_modules\bcry
pt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.22
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.11.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.7 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\backup\My-Twitter
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\backup\My-Twitter\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: can you describe , copy/paste the error that shows up when you are trying to install `bcrypt` ?

Comment: well it looks that its unable to find opessl headers, since you are on windows machine, take a look at `C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\.node-gyp\0.10.22\deps` there should be an `opessl` folder which contains the openssl headers if not specify `--node-dir` argument to load from previous node source under `.node-gyp` directory for example `npm install bcrypt -V --node-dir='C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\.node-gyp\0.10.3'`

Answer (score 5):

I had pretty much the same problem on Ubuntu 13.10, the error log looked the same and the bcrypt installation stopped at `node-gyp rebuild`. After some searching and updating node and npm I still had the same issues.

I found a solution finally here: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/90 and the problem was the `~/.node-gyp` directory which had unsufficient access rights and simply deleting it did the trick. This is where gyp stores headers and other build files during compilation and if it's gone, gyp will just recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install global windows build tool if you are using windows,
follow this link [bcrypt install instruction](http://npm%20install%20--global%20--production%20windows-build-tools)

> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools